# Given a cumulative distribution function for a random variable Y, find the probability mass function.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am given the following CDF for a random variable Y.

```
F(x) = 0, x < 1
F(x) = 1 - 1/(2^k), k <= x < k+1 where k = 1, 2, 3, ...
```

I would like to know whether Y is discrete or continuous and then find the appropriate probability mass function. However, I am unsure of where to start. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: For starters, is the function $F(x)$ continuous?

Comment: @kimchilover No I don't believe that F(x) is continuous

Comment: Good!  What does that tell you about the continuity of the random variable $Y$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)